# Object instantiated through a another separate class is not appearing on panel

Tags: java, javafx

I need to create some circles on a panel and I want them to have some properties, which I plan to use in future like orientation, x and y position etc. For this, I created a general class Robot which extends circle. But, when I am creating an object of this class, it is not being created in the panel.

It works if I am not using a separate class and create object directly from Circle. But I need to maintain some variables with each object. Anybody knows what I am doing wrong in below code:

```
class Robot extends Circle
{
    int radius;
    double x;
    double y;
    int orientation;

    Robot(int i) 
    {
       radius = i;
       orientation = getRandomIntCoordinates(360);
       System.out.println("Inside the constructor");
    }

    private int getRandomIntCoordinates(int range)
    {
        Random randInt = new Random();
        return randInt.nextInt(range);
    }
}

//Inside Another class
private void loadPlayers(Pane playground)
    {
        robot = new Robot(25);
        robot.relocate(200,200);
        robot.setFill(Color.RED);

        /*for(int i =0; i<100; i++)
        {
            particles.add(new Circle(7, Color.GREEN));
            particles.get(i).relocate(getRandomCoordinates(720), getRandomCoordinates(520));
        }*/
        //playground.getChildren().addAll(particles);
        playground.getChildren().add(robot);
    }
```

Update: I have noticed that nothing gets added to the pane in case I am adding the object of class Robot, while it works flawlessly in case Circle's object is used. Is this a limitation with this inbuilt method? If yes, what can I do to overcome this?

Comment: What's the type of `playground.getChildren()`?

Comment: @MichałSzydłowski playground.getChildren is an inbuilt method in JavaFX  to add child nodes in a pane. What exactly do you mean by type?

Comment: @James_D Can you please help me with this question?

Answer (score 0):

A circle has x and y co-ordinates and a radius, you don't need to duplicate those values in your inherited Robot class.  You do need to set the radius and position values of the circle appropriately (e.g. by calling the super constructor) or you won't see the circle.

[image: robots]

```
import javafx.animation.Animation;
import javafx.animation.TranslateTransition;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.DoubleProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleDoubleProperty;
import javafx.geometry.Point2D;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.scene.transform.Rotate;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

import java.util.Random;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class BorgCollective extends Application {

    private static final int PLAYGROUND_SIZE = 300;

    private static final int NUM_ROBOTS   = 500;
    private static final int ROBOT_RADIUS = 10;

    private final Random random = new Random(42);

    class Robot extends Circle {
        private static final int PATROL_LENGTH = 60;
        private DoubleProperty orientation = new SimpleDoubleProperty();

        public double getOrientation() {
            return orientation.get();
        }

        public DoubleProperty orientationProperty() {
            return orientation;
        }

        public void setOrientation(double orientation) {
            this.orientation.set(orientation);
        }

        public Robot(int radius) {
            super(radius);

            orientation.set(
                    random.nextInt(360)
            );

            patrol();
        }

        private void patrol() {
            Rotate rotate = new Rotate(orientation.get());
            Point2D unitVector = rotate.transform(new Point2D(1, 0));
            Point2D patrolVector = unitVector.multiply(PATROL_LENGTH);

            TranslateTransition patrolAnimation = new TranslateTransition(
                    Duration.seconds(2), 
                    this
            );
            patrolAnimation.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
            patrolAnimation.setAutoReverse(true);

            patrolAnimation.setFromX(0);
            patrolAnimation.setFromY(0);
            patrolAnimation.setByX(patrolVector.getX());
            patrolAnimation.setByY(patrolVector.getY());

            patrolAnimation.play();
        }

        public void relocateWithinPatrolRegionSize(int regionSize) {
            int mx = ROBOT_RADIUS + Robot.PATROL_LENGTH;
            int my = mx;

            int dx = random.nextInt(regionSize - 2 * (ROBOT_RADIUS + PATROL_LENGTH));
            int dy = random.nextInt(regionSize - 2 * (ROBOT_RADIUS + PATROL_LENGTH));

            setCenterX(mx + dx);
            setCenterY(my + dy);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        Pane playground = new Pane();
        playground.setPrefSize(
                PLAYGROUND_SIZE,
                PLAYGROUND_SIZE
        );

        IntStream
                .range(0, NUM_ROBOTS)
                .mapToObj(i ->
                                createRobot()
                )
                .collect(
                        Collectors.toCollection(
                                playground::getChildren
                        )
                );

        stage.setScene(new Scene(playground));
        stage.show();
    }

    private Robot createRobot() {
        Robot robot = new Robot(ROBOT_RADIUS);
        robot.setFill(randomColor());
        robot.relocateWithinPatrolRegionSize(PLAYGROUND_SIZE);

        return robot;
    }

    private Color randomColor() {
        return Color.rgb(
                random.nextInt(256),
                random.nextInt(256),
                random.nextInt(256)
        );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```